# Concatenate a set of column values based on another column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Given a Pandas dataframe which has a few labeled series in it, say *Name* and *Villain*.

Say the dataframe has values such: 
**Name**: {'Batman', 'Batman', 'Spiderman', 'Spiderman', 'Spiderman', 'Spiderman'} 
**Villain**: {'Joker', 'Bane', 'Green Goblin', 'Electro', 'Venom', 'Dr Octopus'}

In total the above dataframe has 2 series(or columns) each with six datapoints.

Now, based on the *Name*, I want to concatenate 3 more columns: *FirstName, LastName, LoveInterest* to each datapoint.

The result of which adds 'Bruce; Wayne; Catwoman' to every row which has Name as Batman. And 'Peter; Parker; MaryJane' to every row which has Name as Spiderman.

The final result should be a dataframe containing 5 columns(series) and 6 rows each.

Comment: in pandas this is called a `merge`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a classic inner-join scenario. In `pandas`, use the `merge` module-level function:

```
In [13]: df1
Out[13]: 
        Name       Villain
0     Batman         Joker
1     Batman          Bane
2  Spiderman  Green Goblin
3  Spiderman       Electro
4  Spiderman         Venom
5  Spiderman   Dr. Octopus

In [14]: df2
Out[14]: 
  FirstName LastName LoveInterest       Name
0     Bruce    Wayne     Catwoman     Batman
1     Peter   Parker     MaryJane  Spiderman

In [15]: pd.DataFrame.merge(df1,df2,on='Name')
Out[15]: 
        Name       Villain FirstName LastName LoveInterest
0     Batman         Joker     Bruce    Wayne     Catwoman
1     Batman          Bane     Bruce    Wayne     Catwoman
2  Spiderman  Green Goblin     Peter   Parker     MaryJane
3  Spiderman       Electro     Peter   Parker     MaryJane
4  Spiderman         Venom     Peter   Parker     MaryJane
5  Spiderman   Dr. Octopus     Peter   Parker     MaryJane
```

Comment: If the merge was instead on two columns, say Name and Gender, is it still the same merge?

Comment: @Yaitzme It depends on what you are trying to accomplish. Read the documentation, especially if you aren't familiar with SQL joins: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-joining-merging

Comment: Works perfect for me! Thank you!